# Using Bulit-in Http Module instead of Request Module on Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, request

I want to send form data to web-server by using Node.js, So I use "request" module that is very famous in nodeland. And It's cool, There is no problem, But because of some reason (write-stream encoding non-supported), I have to change it to built-in module, "http".

I think beneath codes are same to post some data to web-server,  When I using "request" module, There is no problem so can get `200 response`, success to sending data.

But in "http" module, I got a `302 response` that redirects to another page. and failed post data. I don't know what is problem with, maybe it is something URL trouble, http use 'host and path' on the other hand, request use 'url' . I don't know how can I solve this, I stucked 2 days, please let me know If you have some hints..

Thanks.

**By Using "Request" Module**

```
function postFormByRequestModule() {

   request({
        url: 'http://finance.naver.com/item/board_act.nhn',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        method: 'POST',
        form: {
            code:'000215',
            mode: 'write',
            title: 'This is Title',
            body:'This is body'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, response.body);
        }
    });
}
```

**By Using "Http" Module**

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
            code:'000215',
            mode: 'write',
            title: 'This is Title',
            body:'This is body'
});


var options = {
    host: 'finance.naver.com',
    path: '/item/board_act.nhn',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

function postFormByBuiltInHttpModule() {
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in http client does not automatically follow forwards, whereas the `request` module does (and has many other "high level" features). So if you want to continue using the built-in client, you will need to manually check `res.headers.location` and retry the request at that url.